# Dropbox iOS SDK always returns 'YES' for isLinked:

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox

I'm using the iOS Dropbox SDK and want to check if my App is already linked with a Dropbox account. So I do:

```
if (self.isLinked) {
    NSLog(@"linked");
}
```

However `self.isLinked` always returns `YES`. Even after cleaning and resetting the iPhone Simulator.

---

This only occurs when running in the iOS simulator not on a real device. I don't know why this happens, but the Dropbox SDK on the Simulator also is linked if its host Mac is linked with a Dropbox account.

To get realistic behavior in the Simulator unlink your Mac in the Dropbox Preferences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometime in mid-2012 (can't find the iOS SDK version log) the Dropbox iOS SDK behaviour changed to retain 'link' status through uninstall/reinstall of an app (even on device). As a result, apps that perform some action on receiving the 'linked' callback (like mine) would not work after a reinstall.

One solution is to unlink on first-run. Something like so:

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:HAS_RUN_KEY] == nil)
    {
        // ensure you have a DBSession to unlink
        if ([DBSession sharedSession] == nil)
        {
            DBSession* dbSession = [[[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:DROPBOX_KEY appSecret:DROPBOX_SECRET root:kDBRootAppFolder] autorelease];
            [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
        }

        // unlink
        [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];

        // set 'has run' flag
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:HAS_RUN_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: While my problem was a more special case (dropbox keeps link in simulator if mac is linked) your solution also applies to any other possible linking problems. This can prevent a lot of headache. Thanks, I will integrate this in my App.

Comment: @codingFriend1 You should also make this an answer. Thanks, I was going nuts over this.

Comment: what is HAS_RUN_KEY over here??

Comment: @Bhushan the `HAS_RUN_KEY` in the code snippet above is just a reference to some NSString that is used as a key for an NSUserDefaults boolean that we use to track whether the user has run the app before or not. It is only used to illustrate a super-basic way to unlink on first run.