# Dropbox iOS SDK unnecessarily creates conflicted copy after restore

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

My iOS app periodically uploads files to a Dropbox app folder using their [Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync). When overwriting existing files, everything seems to work fine until a restore occurs.

After a reset and restore (using iTunes backup), the link to Dropbox is retained (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13136066/1148702), but something isn't quite right. When overwriting an existing file in the Dropbox app folder, a conflicted copy is created by Dropbox, but only on the initial write. Subsequently, there is no issue with conflicted copies.

Below is how I am doing my writing to Dropbox, and checking for an existing file. I have removed error checking in this snippet.

```
- (void)writeDataToDropbox:(NSData *)data inFileAtPath:(NSString *)pathString {
    DBPath *path = [[DBPath root] childPath:pathString];
    DBFile *file;
    DBFileInfo *info = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] fileInfoForPath:path error:nil];
    if (info) {
        file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] openFile:path error:nil];
    } else {
        file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:path error:nil];
    }
    [file writeData:data error:nil];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your restore of the device is restoring an old state of the cache/metadata in the Sync SDK, so when you writeData again, you're actually uploading "on top of" an old version, causing the conflict. If you want to make sure you're on the latest version, you would need to register an observer to wait for all the new remove changes to download first, and then update before writing any additional local changes.

Comment: @Greg thanks for the tip. I don't think the "old state" of the cache/metadata is actually old. I'm baking up, resetting, and restoring all in a short time period, in order to test this situation. Regardless: I'm not sure what your steps to resolve actually mean. What are the "new remove changes"? How do I register an observer to observe these? How do I ask the Sync SDK to update? I wish this were more clear in the documentation :-/ (Maybe I'm just missing something obvious!)

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to say "new remote changes". This part of the tutorial covers the observers and updating: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios#observers Also, check out the example apps included with the SDK to see it all in action.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just encountered a similar situation with Dropbox on ios.
Going through the simulator files, it seems that when you do operation with Dropbox, you actually have a local mirror of files and datastores that Dropbox keeps - as long as the account is linked to you're app.

**When you initiate a link between the account and the app, the mirror will start blank**.
It seems that after the initialization of that mirror, they appropriately manage online operations (i.e. they know if they need to invalidate the mirrored data, and if so, they download the data appropriately).

But what apparently happens is that **if you immediately fetch files before the first initialization of the local mirror, then they don't pass the request to their servers, and treat the request as if the result is null**.

So in your case, **I'd say that you created the second copy locally on the device, because "you didn't see" that there's an existing file online**.
The conflict arouse afterwords, when Dropbox saw two different files with the same file-name.

A solution might be waiting a few seconds, or maybe attach an observer to something (if I'll find to what - I'll update...)

**------ Update ------**

Check out the documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFilesystem

> @property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL completedFirstSync
>
> When a user’s account is first linked, the filesystem needs to be
>   synced with the server before it can be used. This property indicates
>   whether the first sync has completed and the filesystem is ready to
>   use.

So what I did is to check first thing in the setup phase this property, if not ready, trigger the function with "perform:selector:afterDelay" and return.

But I actually needed one more step - as I noticed it didn't work properly. What I needed to do in addition was to **perform the the basic Dropbox initializations on the main thread** (though all of the sync operation are in a dedicated thread in the background)